# Error using d3.js filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, boxplot

The following code works for filtering:

```
 d3.csv("b1.csv", function(csv) {
var data = [];
csv = csv.filter(function(row) {
if(0){
return row['Expt'] == 1001 || row['Expt'] == 1002;
}
if(1){
return row['Expt'] == 1002 || row['Expt']==1001;
} 
})
```

But if i take out one part like this it wont work:

```
 d3.csv("b1.csv", function(csv) {
var data = [];
csv = csv.filter(function(row) {
if(0){
return row['Expt'] == 1001 || row['Expt'] == 1002;
}
if(1){
return row['Expt'] == 1002  /*||  row['Expt']==1001 */;
} 
})
```

Can someone tell me why that is causing an error. Its giving me an error saying it is of uncaught type and the some specific function cannot identify what type it is of.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to take out the part with the operator:

```
d3.csv("b1.csv", function(csv) {
   var data = [];
   csv = csv.filter(function(row) {
      if(0){
         return row['Expt'] == 1001 || row['Expt'] == 1002;
      }
      if(1){
         return row['Expt'] == 1002 /* || row['Expt']==1001 */;
     }
   } 
})
```

Comment: sorry thats my bad. I wrote it wrongly here. It is ok in real code, thats not the problem